# XAML - Binding a radio button to a text box

Tags: xaml, data-binding, textbox, radio-button

I'm doing an application using blend 4.
I want to display a different text when different radio button is chosen.
Meaning, when user chose MB radio button, text should display MB.
if user chose GB radio button, text should display GB.
Thanks
Yair

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices, one is to use a Listbox to contain your options, you I have read that you can use style so the options be shown as radio buttons, so you can explore that path, the code would be like this.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox1">
   <ListBoxItem Content="MB" />
   <ListBoxItem Content="GB" IsSelected="False" />
</ListBox>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Content, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=listbox1}" />
```

Using separated radio buttons, that would need to implemented by code from visual studio I think, in the click event of the radio buttons, like this

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.Click, RadioButton2.Click
   TextBox1.Text = sender.Content
End Sub
```